# ¿Cómo imprimo un float con todos sus dígitos, sin notación científica?

Tags: c++, variables, bigdecimal

Quiero imprimir en *C++* un número que puede llevar 5 dígitos a la derecha de la coma y 9 a la izquierda como máximo, y el número a imprimir me lo genera este código:

```
float *i,*n;int *P; i = new float; P = new int; n = new float;
cout << "\n       Ingrese cu\240ntos periodos desea tabular[meses]: "  ; cin >> *n;
cout << "       Ingrese el capital o valor presente: "              ; cin >> *P;
cout << "       Ingrese el porcentaje[%] de la tasa de inter\202s: "; cin >> *i;

for(float k=0,*F; k<*n; k++)
{
    F = new float; *F = (float)(*P) * (1 + ((*n)*(*i/100)));
    cout<<"|"<< setw(2) << k <<"-"<<k+1<<setw(3)
        <<"|"<< setw(8) << *P << setw(10)
        <<"|"<< setw(10)<< (float)(*P) * (*i)/100 << setw(6)
        <<"|"<< setw(8) << *F << setw(12) 
        <<"|"<<endl;
}
```

> Input: 5, 1200000 y 12

En la terminal imprime por lo tanto:

```
| 0-1  | 1200000         |    144000     |1.92e+006           |
| 1-2  | 1200000         |    144000     |1.92e+006           |
| 2-3  | 1200000         |    144000     |1.92e+006           |
| 3-4  | 1200000         |    144000     |1.92e+006           |
| 4-5  | 1200000         |    144000     |1.92e+006           |
```

Aquellos números con notación científica son a los que me refiero, siguiendo el ejemplo, el `1.92e+006` sería en realidad `1920000;` y puesto que, en lugar de valores tan altos, también aceptaría decimales en `*P`, debería poder imprimir aquel número con decimales.

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunas cosas que te estas complicado primero en tu problema no necesitas manejar punteros para leer numeros asi te evitas hacer castings innecesarios, otra cosas en tu iterador for cambia el tipo de dato de la variable k de float a int.

Por ultimo para que te muestre todos los digitos del float usa el manipulador [fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) y con la funcion [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) de cout manejas la cantidad de decimales a imprimir.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float i,n;
    int P;

    cout<< "\n       Ingrese cu\240ntos periodos desea tabular[meses]: "  ;
    cin>>n;

    cout<< "       Ingrese el capital o valor presente: "              ;
    cin>>P;

    cout<< "       Ingrese el porcentaje[%] de la tasa de inter\202s: ";
    cin>>i;

    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        float F = P * (1 + ((n)*(i/100.0)));
        cout.precision(2);
        cout<<fixed <<
              "|"<< k <<"-"<<k+1<<
              "|"<<P<<
              "|"<<P * i/100.0<<
              "|"<<F<<
              "|"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias aunque, la tabla imprime absolutamente todos lo números con aquella cantidad de decimales, ¿no es posible que ponga sólo si los tiene, es decir, que si tengo un `1` no me lo imprima como `1.00`, pero si tengo un número decimal como `123000.45678` me lo imprima tal cual?

Comment: forzosamente tienes que especificar la precisión, aunque puedes validar que para los números sin decimales no muestre los ceros después del punto decimal.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente