# ¿Como puedo hacer para que me de el resultado correcto?

Tags: c++, funciones, variables, struct

Hola buen dia al que lea esto, estoy haciendo un programa con `struct` en c++ que guarde los datos de dos personas para calcular su IMC y su metabolismo basal, pero al momento de calcular el metabolismo basal el resultado sale incorrecto el resultado se muestra como algo como esto 5.7e+002.Ya comprobe y las variables de la formula son la correctas, tambien sus valores y tambien revise la formuala y esta escrita correctamente. Ya probe con variables `float`,`double` y `long double`
y todas con el mismo resultado incorrecto e incluso no declarando la variable de metabolismo en el `struct`. Le agradezco de antemano a la persona que me ayude a ver mi error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

struct persona{
    
    char nombre[90];
    int edad;
    float peso,altura,imc;
    char sexo;
    double metabolismo;
    
    
}persona1,persona2;

void rellenar1()
{
    
    
    cout<<"Introduzca el nombre de la persona 1: "; cin.getline(persona1.nombre,90,'\n');
    cout<<"Introduzca la edad de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1.edad;
    cout<<"Introduzca el peso en kg de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1.peso;
    cout<<"Introduzca la altura en mts de la persona 1: "; cin>>persona1.altura;
    cout<<"Introduzca el sexo de la persona (masculino=m),(femenino=f): "; cin>>persona1.sexo;
    

}

void metabolismo1(float peso,float altura,int edad,int actividad)
{   
 

 
altura=altura*100;
    if(persona1.sexo=='m')
    {
        switch(actividad)
        {
            case 1:
                
                cout<<peso<<endl;
                cout<<altura<<endl;
                cout<<edad<<endl;
                cout<<actividad<<endl;
                    
    persona1.metabolismo=66.47+(13.75*peso)+(5*altura)-(6.755*edad);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout<<persona1.metabolismo;
                break;
                
        }
    }
    
}

    



void mostrar1()
{
    short int actividad;
    strupr(persona1.nombre);
    cout<<"\n\nDatos de: "<<persona1.nombre;
    cout<<"\n\nEdad: "<<persona1.edad;
    cout<<"\nPeso: "<<persona1.peso<<" kg";
    cout<<"\nEstatura: "<<persona1.altura<<" mts";
    cout<<"\nSexo: "<<persona1.sexo;
    
    persona1.imc=(persona1.peso)/(pow(persona1.altura,2));
     cout.precision(3);
    cout<<"\nIMC: "<<persona1.imc<<endl;    
    
    cout<<"\nIndique el tipo de actividad fisica de la persona: \n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  "; 
    cin>>actividad;
    while((actividad<1)||(actividad>5))
    {
        cout<<"\t\nIngrese el numero de la opcion (1-5): ";
            cout<<"\n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  "; 
        
        cin>>actividad;
    }
    
    
    metabolismo1(persona1.peso,persona1.altura,persona1.edad,actividad);
    
    
}


int main ()
{
        rellenar1();
        mostrar1();

    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta:

```
cout<<fixed<<persona1.metabolismo;
```

Puedes verlo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67958/c%C3%B3mo-imprimo-un-float-con-todos-sus-d%C3%ADgitos-sin-notaci%C3%B3n-cient%C3%ADfica)

Lo que no sé es por qué se muestra en notación científica. Es decir, cogiendo de tu mismo código la función y simplificando para que se vea:

```
void metabolismo1(float peso,float altura,int edad,int actividad)
{
    cout<<peso*2<<endl; //160 (con peso = 80)
    persona1.metabolismo=peso*2;
    cout.precision(2);
    cout<<persona1.metabolismo; //1.6e+02 (con peso = 80)
}
```

Y realmente no sé por qué es así

Por otro lado el código está algo lioso y te pongo algunas mejoras.
Por empezar por el principio, y puesto que estás en `c++` y no  en  `c`, has de cambiar las cabeceras.
Así, has de usar `cmath` en lugar de `math.h`y `cstring` en lugar de `string.h`. La librería `conio.h` no hace nada y la deberías quitar.

Luego declaras variables globales, que son `persona1` y `persona2`. Eso es una mala práctica. Mejor declarar las variables locales y pasarlas, si es necesario, por referencia a las funciones.

Tampoco tiene sentido pasar el peso, altura y edad a la función `metabolismo1`. Puedes pasar a la persona y de ahí trabajar con sus datos.

Con estos cambios el código podría ser así:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

struct persona
{
    char nombre[90];
    int edad;
    float peso,altura,imc;
    char sexo;
    double metabolismo;
};

void rellenar1(persona& persona1)
{
    cout<<"Introduzca el nombre de la persona 1: ";
    cin.getline(persona1.nombre,90,'\n');
    cout<<"Introduzca la edad de la persona 1: ";
    cin>>persona1.edad;
    cout<<"Introduzca el peso en kg de la persona 1: ";
    cin>>persona1.peso;
    cout<<"Introduzca la altura en mts de la persona 1: ";
    cin>>persona1.altura;
    cout<<"Introduzca el sexo de la persona (masculino=m),(femenino=f): ";
    cin>>persona1.sexo;
}

void metabolismo1(persona persona1, short int actividad)
{
    float altura=persona1.altura*100;
    if(persona1.sexo=='m')
    {
        switch(actividad)
        {
        case 1:

            cout<<persona1.peso<<endl;
            cout<<persona1.altura<<endl;
            cout<<persona1.edad<<endl;
            cout<<actividad<<endl;
            persona1.metabolismo=66.47+(13.75*persona1.peso)+(5*persona1.altura)-(6.755*persona1.edad);
            cout.precision(2);
            cout<<fixed<<persona1.metabolismo;
            break;
        }
    }
}


void mostrar1(persona& persona1)
{
    short int actividad;
    //strupr (persona1.nombre);
    cout<<"\n\nDatos de: "<<persona1.nombre;
    cout<<"\n\nEdad: "<<persona1.edad;
    cout<<"\nPeso: "<<persona1.peso<<" kg";
    cout<<"\nEstatura: "<<persona1.altura<<" mts";
    cout<<"\nSexo: "<<persona1.sexo;

    persona1.imc=(persona1.peso)/(pow(persona1.altura,2));
    cout.precision(3);
    cout<<"\nIMC: "<<persona1.imc<<endl;

    cout<<"\nIndique el tipo de actividad fisica de la persona: \n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  ";
    cin>>actividad;
    while((actividad<1)||(actividad>5))
    {
        cout<<"\t\nIngrese el numero de la opcion (1-5): ";
        cout<<"\n1-Poco o ningun ejercicio\n2-Ejercicio ligero (1-3 dias a la semana)\n3-Ejercicio moderado(3-5 dias a la semana)\n4-Ejercicio fuerte(6-7 dias a la semana)\n5-Ejercicio muy fuerte (dos veces por dia, entrenamiento muy duros)\nIngrese el numero de la opcion:  ";

        cin>>actividad;
    }
    metabolismo1(persona1, actividad);
}


int main ()
{
    persona p;
    rellenar1(p);
    mostrar1(p);
    return 0;
}
```